# drawing shapes with mouse in java

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, shapes

I am working on a simple panting project that allow the user to select a shape from `ComboBox` then draw it on the panel. Problem is when user choose any type of shapes and try to draw it on panel no shape appears.

here is my panel class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Shapes extends JPanel {
    private MyLine[] lines = new MyLine[100];
    private MyRectangle[] recs;
    private MyOval[] ovals;
    int ShapeType = 0;

    int LC = 0;// conter for number of lines
    int RC = 0;// conter for number of rectable
    int OC = 0;// conter for number of ovals

    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;

    Shapes() {

        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBounds(0, 100, 300, 300);
        MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
        this.addMouseListener(handler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

    }

    public int getShapeType() {
        return ShapeType;
    }

    public void setShapeType(int ShapeType) {
        this.ShapeType = ShapeType;
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter implements
            MouseMotionListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getX();
            repaint();
            System.out.println(x1 + " " + y1);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getX();
            lines[LC] = new MyLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            LC++;
            System.out.println(x2 + " " + y2);
            repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getX();
            System.out.println(x2 + " dragged " + y2);
            repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        if (ShapeType == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < LC; i++) {

                lines[i].draw(g);
            }
        }

        if (ShapeType == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < LC; i++) {
                lines[i].draw(g);
            }
        }

        if (ShapeType == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < LC; i++) {
                lines[i].draw(g);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MyLine Class

```
package painter;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class MyLine extends MyShape {
    MyLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.c = c;

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(500, 200, 300, 400);
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) short but compilable example that will reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your panel is way too small: it's 300 by 300 pixels, but when you draw the line, you start it at (500,200) which is out of the bounds of your panel:

```
g.drawLine(500, 200, 300, 400);
```

Try drawing it closer to the upper-left corner:

```
 g.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 400);
```

Comment: it's working now
but still a problem when i drawing lines
an then choose to draw Recatngle
all lines gonna to be deleted from the panel
how i can draw many shapes on the same panel ?!
at the same time

Comment: Well, there is a number of errors in your code. Let's start by paintComponent: you don't need those if's because no matter what type of figure is chosen, you want to paint them all.
Next, you have two if's that are the same (test for ShapeType == 1) and in each and every if you draw only the lines. Try to fix these and repost the code if you need more help.